# Perform a query over a query result MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to query over a query to find unmatched id's. I have a list of ID's and I want all the info I have about them, so I did a simple query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN(list_of_ids);
```

Please notice "list_of_ids" is a list containing 274 numbers such as the example below (formatted like `(number1, number2, number3)`

```
+---------+   
|   id    |   
+---------+   
|  112234 |       
|  345657 |  
|   45332 |        
| 1234665 |     
|  213423 |  
+---------+
```

I got outputted 151 rows, so there's some ID's I got no info about. I want to see which are those IDs just to do a quality check and see if there was some error with the query/typo or is it that I really don't have any info about those (which I doubt).

I've tried some methods that I found searching, but none of those worked (as using the function `VALUES` and creating temporary tables)

I know I can simply create a new table with a column and this values and then do something along the line of

```
SELECT * id2 FROM table2 JOIN table1 WHERE id2 NOT LIKE id1";
```

(have'nt tested this, but I guess it might work)

But I feel this is something that I will face somewhat frequently in the future, so I prefer a more direct way of doing this rather than creating a table each time. Also I think learning a more direct way is preferable over creating and droping tables for "simple" tasks like this

Is there a way of doing something like

```
SELECT id2 FROM subquery JOIN table1 WHERE id2 != id1 FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (list_of_ids)) AS subquery;
```

I know, this would never work, but just to give a kind of flavor of what I want to achieve.
Sorry for the eyebleeds!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as one way.

For example, table1 looks like below:

```
create table table1 (id1 int);
insert into table1 values (12345),(112234),(345657),(213423),(223344);
```

table2 needs a recursive call using the WITH clause (which is a common way to expand to multiple rows).
So list_of_ids needs to treated as a character constant.

```
with recursive table2(id2,wk_ids) as (
  select cast(NULL as signed), '112234,345657,45332,1234665,213423' as list_of_ids
  union select
    cast(substring_index(wk_ids,',',1) as signed),
    substring(wk_ids,instr(wk_ids,',')+1)
    from table2 where wk_ids<>''
)
select id2 from table1 right outer join table2 on id1=id2 where id1 is null and id2 is not null;
```

Comment: I think this made the trick! Can you please link a source for what is going on in this type of query or give me some keywords to do my research? I think there are several things going on, more than just a "recursive table". I found this type of thing pretty advanced but would love to learn about it! Thanks!

Comment: The query of table2 is a "recursive common table expression" that generate by spliting list_of_ids with comma. Please perform "SELECT * FROM table2". you can see the split list_of_ids. "outer join" can find unmatched data in order to NULL that the records of joined table are.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `UNION` function with `NOT IN` on the second part like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN(list_of_ids) UNION SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN(list_of_ids);
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help!
Unfortunately this is not exactly what I'm looking for. Your solution returns all the rows from my table NOT included in my ids list, which is not what I want. I need to see, from the ids list, those that have no match on my table!

Thanks again!